# Use Oauth in Swagger API

Tags: api, oauth, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

I'm building API using swagger and so far I created get/insert/update and delete jobs, and now I'm trying to use Oauth to secure my API

I have used

```
securityDefinitions: 
  job_auth: 
    type: oauth2 
    authorizationUrl: http://localhost:10010/auth 
    flow: implicit 
    scopes: 
      write:jobs: modify jobs in your account 
      read:jobs: get your jobs
```

And in my /get function i used
`paths:

```
/jobs:
# binds a127 app logic to a route
x-swagger-router-controller: job
get:
  description: Returns the job list
  # used as the method name of the controller
  operationId: getAllJobs
  responses:
    "200":
      description: Success
      schema:
      $ref: "#/definitions/GetJobsListResponse"

  security:
    - job_auth:
      - read:jobs `
```

In swagger editor , now it shows

Security
job_auth (OAuth 2.0)   Authenticate(Button)

Flow    implicit
Authorization URL   http://localhost:10010/auth

Scopes

write:jobs  modify jobs in your account
read:jobs   get your jobs

now i want to access job list using

http://localhost:10010/jobs

but it gives something like this

{
"message": "unknown security handler: job_auth",
"code": "server_error",
"statusCode": 403
}

can anyone help me how to access http://localhost:10010/jobs and set
Authenticate in Oauth properly, I'm new to this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use swagger with OAuth API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14884274/how-to-use-swagger-with-oauth-api)

Comment: You asked this a couple of hours ago, then deleted it and asked it again right? Please don't do that. You can edit your question all you like, but deleting and re-asking to try to get more attention is grounds for having your account banned. Note: users with >10,000 rep points can still see your deleted questions.

Comment: @Hack-R i have deleted it because  I  thought  it's not clear, so that's why I posted new one

Comment: which is why @Hack-R mentioned the feature of editing your question. :)