# How can I add Spring Security authentication to Swagger?

Tags: spring-security, annotations, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

How can I add Spring Security authentication to Swagger **using** annotations?

My `SwaggerConfig` is like:

```java
private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
    return new ApiInfoBuilder().title("Spring REST Sample with Swagger")
            .description("Spring REST Sample with Swagger").license("Apache License Version 2.0").version("1.0")
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Docket docket() {
    Docket docket = new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2);
    docket.protocols(new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("http")));
    docket.apiInfo(apiInfo()).select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.zycus.endpoint"))
            .paths(PathSelectors.any()).build();
    return docket;
}
```

Comment: What authentication are you using? Username-password / token / Oauth ? Spring security is irrelevant here.

Comment: @gaganbm i am using Oauth2 Authentication.

Comment: You need to provide security schema and security definitions. You may find some examples here http://stackoverflow.com/a/34020486/564503. Looks like it doesn't work properly with old versions of swagger. Have a look at https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/870